# Delphi "не нравится" .rc файл

Tags: delphi

В интернете нашёл исходник модуля для разграничения прав доступа. 
(http://www.interface.ru/home.asp?artId=17969)

```
procedure TRightsForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var f: TResourceStream;
begin
  mode := 1;
// загружаем данные о правилах из ресурса.
  f := TResourceStream.create(Hinstance, 'rigths.RC',  PChar('RT_RCDATA'));
  try
    LoadFromStream(f);
  finally
    f.free;
  end;}
{$IFDEF isadmin}
  RightsView.PopupMenu := PopupMenu1;
{$ENDIF
end;
```

В папке проекта есть "rights.txt" файл. В Delphi 10.1 berlin захожу Project->Resources and images' и создаю "rights.rc" файл,{$R 'rigths.res' 'rigths.rc'} появляется в project1.dpr, но при выполнении оператор TResourceStream.create(Hinstance, 'rigths.RC',  PChar('RT_RCDATA')) выводит ощибку:

```
"bad character in source input",
```

а если добавляю rights.txt  как ресурс тогда не компилируется и выводит:

```
Project1.exe raised exception class ERESNotFound with message 'Resource rights not found'.
```

может быть из за неопознанных символов в rights.txt?
[image: PopupMenu with access rights]

[image: rights.txt]

Comment: "но при компиляции"? - при выполнении

Comment: @Igor если добавляю rights.txt  как ресурс тогда не компилируется и выводиь "Resource rights not found", а если добавляю ресурс rights.rc тогда не выпольняется и выводит ошибку: "bad character in source input".

Answer (score 1):

Содержимое `rights.rc`:

```
RESID_RIGHTS RCDATA "rights.txt"
```

В коде:

```
f := TResourceStream.Create(hInstance, 'RESID_RIGHTS', RT_RCDATA);
```

Comment: тоже самое: "bad character in source input", хотя мне интересно где вы нашли в rights.rc файле RESID_RIGHTS RCDATA "rights.txt" ? Чем открываете?

Comment: @Delphi159 я не нашел. Это то, что должно быть в rc файле, который компилируется компилятором ресурсов в res файл, который линкуется в exe файл. А у Вас что в rights.rc?

Comment: а я open->save as rights.rc, потом в "Project->resources an images" --> add и выбираю rights.rc.

Comment: тоже самое: "bad character in source input",
в "Resources and images" resource identifier "Resource_1", поэтому вместо RESID_RIGHTS в rights.rc файле и в коде  вставил Resource_1, но напрасно.

Comment: @Delphi159 "Сложные действия состоят из простых шагов." Если Вы думаете, что дело в содержимом rights.txt, напишите туда что-то простое, без специальных символов. Убедитесь, что Вы можете добиться компиляции ресурса и линковки его в программу. Следующий шаг - отработайте чтение содержимого ресурса в стрим в ран-тайм. Убедитесь, что содержимое стрима соответствует тому, что находилось в файле rights.txt. Потом вернемся к содержимому файла rights.txt.